# Filter results using multiple groups of checkboxes

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create an on-page job filter which has the option of filtering results by both job position (e.g. perm, temp) and location (e.g. uk, scotland, wales).

I have a working solution but it seems very verbose and would get even more complicated if a third filter was added. I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of a cleaner and more scalable solution.

The expected behaviour for the filter is as follows:

- No checkboxes selected: show all jobs
- At least one position checkbox selected: filter by position
- At least one location checkbox selected: filter by location
- At least one position and location checkbox selected: filter by both

You can view it as a pen here:
https://codepen.io/acnorrisuk/pen/RwarJYQ

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    positionFilter: [],
    locationFilter: [],
    jobs: [{
        'name': 'Job A',
        'position': 'temp',
        'location': 'uk'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Job B',
        'position': 'perm',
        'location': 'uk'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Job C',
        'position': 'temp',
        'location': 'wales'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Job D',
        'position': 'perm',
        'location': 'wales'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Job E',
        'position': 'temp',
        'location': 'scotland'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Job F',
        'position': 'perm',
        'location': 'scotland'
      },
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    filteredJobs: function() {
      const positionFilter = this.positionFilter
      const locationFilter = this.locationFilter
      if (positionFilter.length && locationFilter.length) {
        return this.jobs.filter(function(job) {
          return positionFilter.includes(job.position) && locationFilter.includes(job.location)
        });
      } else if (positionFilter.length) {
        return this.jobs.filter(function(job) {
          return positionFilter.includes(job.position)
        });
      } else if (locationFilter.length) {
        return this.jobs.filter(function(job) {
          return locationFilter.includes(job.location)
        });
      } else {
        return this.jobs
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <fieldset>
    <label for="p1">temp</label>
    <input id="p1" type="checkbox" v-model="positionFilter" value="temp">

    <label for="p2">perm</label>
    <input id="p2" type="checkbox" v-model="positionFilter" value="perm">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label for="l1">uk</label>
    <input id="l1" type="checkbox" v-model="locationFilter" value="uk">

    <label for="l2">wales</label>
    <input id="l2" type="checkbox" v-model="locationFilter" value="wales">

    <label for="l3">scotland</label>
    <input id="l3" type="checkbox" v-model="locationFilter" value="scotland">
  </fieldset>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="job in filteredJobs">{{ job.name }} {{ job.position }} {{ job.location }}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: This is probably more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this code can be shortened like this:

```js
computed: 
{
    // combining filters using OR
    filteredJobs() 
    {
      const positionFilter = this.positionFilter
      const locationFilter = this.locationFilter
      return positionFilter.length + locationFilter.length > 0 
        ? this.jobs.filter(job => positionFilter.includes(job.position) || locationFilter.includes(job.location))
        : this.jobs;
    },
    // combining filters using AND
    filteredJobs() 
    {
      const filter = {}
      if (this.positionFilter.length > 0) filter.position = this.positionFilter
      if (this.locationFilter.length > 0) filter.location = this.locationFilter
      const list = Object.entries(filter);
      return list.length > 0 
        ? this.jobs.filter(job => list.every(([key, options]) => options.includes(job[key])))
        : this.jobs;
    }
  }
```

You will filter the jobs only if there is at least one filter in any of the categories. And in this case you will request only those jobs which satisfy at least one of the filters.

Comment: If you have `temp`/`perm` selected, the location checkboxes don't work

Comment: I am not following - could you explain ?

Comment: If you have either `temp`, or `perm` selected, the location filters don't work as they should

Comment: The function combines filters using OR - but can be easily changed to combine using AND.

Comment: Then the filters don't work individually, only in combination

Comment: Well, then apparently you won't be able to make your code more scaleable than it is already ...

Comment: That's much better now you've fixed it. If you answer a question make sure it works first.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the logic behind this, I wouldn't say it's too verbose.

Only changes I can think of are using arrow syntax for your `filter` methods:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    positionFilter: [],
    locationFilter: [],
    jobs: [{
        'name': 'Job A',
        'position': 'temp',
        'location': 'uk'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Job B',
        'position': 'perm',
        'location': 'uk'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Job C',
        'position': 'temp',
        'location': 'wales'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Job D',
        'position': 'perm',
        'location': 'wales'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Job E',
        'position': 'temp',
        'location': 'scotland'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Job F',
        'position': 'perm',
        'location': 'scotland'
      },
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    filteredJobs: function() {
      const positionFilter = this.positionFilter
      const locationFilter = this.locationFilter
      if (positionFilter.length && locationFilter.length) {
        return this.jobs.filter(job => positionFilter.includes(job.position) && locationFilter.includes(job.location));
      } else if (positionFilter.length) {
        return this.jobs.filter(job => positionFilter.includes(job.position));
      } else if (locationFilter.length) {
        return this.jobs.filter(job => locationFilter.includes(job.location));
      }
      return this.jobs
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <fieldset>
    <label for="p1">temp</label>
    <input id="p1" type="checkbox" v-model="positionFilter" value="temp">

    <label for="p2">perm</label>
    <input id="p2" type="checkbox" v-model="positionFilter" value="perm">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label for="l1">uk</label>
    <input id="l1" type="checkbox" v-model="locationFilter" value="uk">

    <label for="l2">wales</label>
    <input id="l2" type="checkbox" v-model="locationFilter" value="wales">

    <label for="l3">scotland</label>
    <input id="l3" type="checkbox" v-model="locationFilter" value="scotland">
  </fieldset>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="job in filteredJobs">{{ job.name }} {{ job.position }} {{ job.location }}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```